# JPA custom serialisation of objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA Entity, that references an object structure, that is passed around and changed. I wish to serialise these objects manually into a single entity column.

Doing this using @PreUpdate and @PostLoad is straightforward.

But changes in these objects do not cause the entity to be persisted, as it is not considered "dirty", as the mutations of the associated objects are not detected by Hibernate. @Embedded and @Embeddable would seem to solve this for a single object, but in this case it is a collection of "embedded" objects.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use  `javax.persistence.AttributeConverter`

**Example:**

The our main entity:

```
@Entity
public class Crate {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private final long id;

    @Convert(converter = AnimalConverter.class)
    private final Animal animal;

    public Crate() {
        this(new Elephant());
    }

    public Crate(final Animal animal) {
        this(0, animal);
    }

    public Crate(final long id, final Animal animal) {
        this.id = id;
        this.animal = animal;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Animal getAnimal() {
        return animal;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        final Crate crate = (Crate) o;
        return id == crate.id && Objects.equals(animal, crate.animal);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, animal);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Crate{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", animal=" + animal +
                '}';
    }
}
```

An "object structure" (Animals in my case) :

```
public interface Animal {
}

public class Elephant implements Animal {

    private final String name;

    public Elephant() {
        this("unknown");
    }

    public Elephant(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Elephant:" + name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        final Elephant elephant = (Elephant) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, elephant.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
}

public class Lion implements Animal{

    private final String name;

    public Lion() {
        this("unknown");
    }

    public Lion(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Lion:" + name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        final Lion lion = (Lion) o;
        return Objects.equals(name, lion.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }
}
```

Converter:

```
public class AnimalConverter implements AttributeConverter<Animal, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final Animal animal) {
        return animal.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Animal convertToEntityAttribute(final String s) {
        String[] split = s.split(":");
        String animalType = split[0];
        String animalName = split[1];
        switch (animalType) {
            case "Elephant":
                return new Elephant(animalName);
            case "Lion":
                return new Lion(animalName);
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And test (I used the Spring JPA with the Hibernate, but it doesn't metter):

```
@DataJpaTest
public class AnimalCrateConverter {

    private final CrateRepo repo;
    private final EntityManager manager;

    @Autowired
    public AnimalCrateConverter(final CrateRepo repo, final EntityManager manager) {
        this.repo = repo;
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @Test
    void saveElephantWithCrate() {
        Elephant elephant = new Elephant();
        Lion lion = new Lion();
        Crate elephantCrate = new Crate(elephant);
        Crate lionCrate = new Crate(lion);
        repo.save(elephantCrate);
        repo.save(lionCrate);
        manager.flush();
        manager.clear();
        Crate actualElephantCrate = repo.findById(elephantCrate.getId()).orElseThrow();
        Crate actualLionCrate = repo.findById(lionCrate.getId()).orElseThrow();
        assertEquals(elephantCrate, actualElephantCrate);
        assertEquals(lionCrate, actualLionCrate);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Good suggestion. But unfortunately does not seem to detect changes to objects. At least not in my case, where it is in fact a collection of objects. Also I need to update multiple columns based on these objects (done in @PrePersist).